# mysql 4.x -> 5.x upgrade related question

Tags: mysql

im upgrading mysql 4.x -> 5.x.

and in my php source there is mysql synxtax following.

```
$pt_sql = "select * from orderlist 
           where condition!='delete' 
            and left(date,10)='$nday' 
           group by id ";
```

how can i change above mysql syntax to mysql 5.x syntax?

if anyone help me much apprecate!

thanks in advance

Comment: it is not SQL query but PHP code. Please provide an SQL query along with exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONDITION` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL 5.0 ([it was not in 4.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)) so it must be in backticks in your queries:

```
select * from orderlist 
where `condition` != 'delete' 
and left(date,10)='$nday' 
group by id
```

You may also want to consider storing the column `date` as a `date` or storing it as `datetime` type and using the DATE function.